# https does not work externally , but http works

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, ssl

I have an website hosted on IIS 7 as http://mywebsite.com. Works fine and publicly accessible.

I now created a https://mywebsite.com/newapplication with self sign certificate. I can access the https://mywebsite.com/newapplication  on local network but not outside the local network. However if I disable the SSL certificate , I can access http://mywebsite.com/newapplication.

Whats causing the problem to access https website externally. any idea or solution ..???

Its very urgent...!!!!

Comment: Are you behind a NAT router? Did you remember to forward port 443?

Comment: Or even firewall on server?

Comment: https uses a different port 443 to http which uses port 80.  Lots of organisations block all ports apart from port 80.  If your the admin, open up the extra port to the server.

Comment: How to find if I am behind NAT ..??? Port 443 is forwarded in my windows 2008 machine .

Comment: I disabled the firewall to test..still does not work

Comment: Does the IP of the server start wit 192.168.x.x,  172.16.x.x. or 10.x.x.x?

Comment: Better question is does the IP of the server differ from the IP address returned at www.whatismyip.com?

Comment: What's the public name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gotta open that port 443 in your external-facing firewall.

Comment: Dos that mean I have done all I can , its some thing network administrator needs to fix ???

Comment: The problem is resolved.....!!I spoke to network administrator at our organization and requested to open port 443.  

Appreciate all the responses..it helped me troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: @bp581 - I lost power on my phone while writing, thus the absence of further comments. Glad you figured it out :)